# Checking if content isn't overflow then remove overflow:scroll using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there any way I can hide scroll bar of a div, e.g.   overflow:hidden; if content of div ***is not*** overflown, as If I make any sense :-).

what I am trying right now is,

```
if($("#MayBeOverFlowDiv").height() <= 300)
        $("#MayBeOverFlowDiv").  // dunno how to add "Overflow:hidden" to to hide scroll bar
```

Comment: How about `overflow: auto`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the CSS style to auto:

```
#MayBeOverFlowDiv{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Which will show a scrollbar only if it's needed. (I.E. If the scroll-height is larger than the element height)

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/75mza/)

If you must use jQuery to do this then you can do like so:

```
$('#MayBeOverFlowDiv').css({overflow:'hidden'});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/75mza/1/)

Answer (score 3):

What about use `auto` as the value for `overflow`:

```
#MayBeOverFlowDiv {
   overflow:auto;
}
```

That way the scrollbar only shows when the content exceeds the height if not doesn't show anything.

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C37ew/)**

Answer (score -1):

Better way:

CSS:

```
#MayBeOverFlowDiv {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 300;
}
```

No javascript needed.

If you *really* want to use javascript:

```
$('#MayBeOverFlowDiv').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```